# What is the type of the following expression in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to understand what is the type of the following statement in Scheme:

```
#&\a
```

what is the type of the expression above?
is it a comment?

Comment: For what scheme implementation? Chicken, guile and kawa all give syntax errors for that.

Answer (score 2):

In Racket, `#&\a` is an immutable [box](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/boxes.html) containing a [symbol](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html).

```
(box? #&\a)  ; #t
(unbox #&\a)  ; 'a
(symbol? (unbox #&\a))  ; #t
(immutable? #&\a)  ; #t
```

Refer to [Reading Boxes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=reading%20boxes#%28part._parse-box%29).

Answer (score 0):

`#&\a` is not valid Scheme code.

Anything starting with `#` is typically a reader macro of some sort. In Scheme all from reading numbers in specific bases, vector literals and booleans start with the `#` and this is remnants from the time Scheme was interpreted under a MacLISP host. It would use reader macro to do the right thing at read time. Common Lisp has the same functionality today.

Examples:

```
'#(1 2 3) ; a vector of 3 elements
#f        ; boolean false (everything else is thruthy)
#x10      ; 16 read in hexadecimal
```

It's not uncommon for an implementation to expand features beyond the report and the report does not ban this. Thus any implementation can add other reader macros and it won't affect Scheme code since you'll never use those in Scheme code, only in the implementers new Scheme dialect. I don't think there exist one Scheme implementation that only implement the report and nothing else.